# How to make resizable grids based on number of items?

Tags: css, user-interface, flexbox, css-grid, user-experience

I am working on a questionnaire [design](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-andras-rhe7wj?file=/index.html), which can have one or more answers, something like this:

[image: multiple answers]

This looks alright for 3 or more answers as in the above screenshot. However, when there's a single or couple of answers, they are taking too much space, resulting in this:

[image: bigger boxes]

**How can I make the boxes smaller if there are fewer answers, still making them look good, i.e. centered and with proper spacing, etc.?**

[image: expected layout]

Here's a working [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-andras-rhe7wj?file=/index.html) where you can see what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may need a different approach with only flexbox

```css
/* custom class */
.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}

/* responsivity class */
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.center-placer {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
<div class="center-placer">
  <div class="box">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    D
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    E
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="center-placer">
    <div class="box">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="center-placer">
    <div class="box">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```